# How to check if arbitrary class instance exists and call its method from another module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

Lets say I have two modules `module1` and `module2` and `module1` can have objects `chair1`, `chair2` and `chair3`. I want to check if one of those objects exist from `module2` and if it does exist run a method on it also from `module2`. Something like:

```
# module2
if ("chair" + str(i)) in globals():
    globals()["chair" + str(i)].carve() # i = 1, 2 or 3
```

This obviously won't work because `chair1`, `chair2` and `chair3` are not in `globals()` of `module2`

What is the best approach to solve this?

**EDIT:**

Rob's answer (`hasattr()`) solves the problem of checking if the object exists in the other module. The second part, about running methods on objects I solved by using dictionary (something like: `obj_names  = {"chair1" : chair1, "chair2" : chair2, "chair3 : chair3}` instead of trying to use `global()` function. As recommended on some other issue this is the most pythonic approach. First part can also be solved with dictionary, like setting `obj_names[i] = 0` if the object doesn't exist.

Btw, for my particular problem I won't be needing more than 10 chairs so using the dictionary is not a bad option. But if the problem was defined so that number of chairs can be any int, than using something like `global()` would be more logical.

Comment: Seems like you have a design issue here...

Answer (score 1):

Try [`hasattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#hasattr):

```
# module2.py
import module1

if hasattr(module1, "chair1"):
    module1.chair1.carve()
```

Comment: Why can't you write `module.chair1.carve()` ? Edit your question and try to more fully explain your design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir):

```
if "chair1" in dir(module1):
    ...
```